# Error Installing Rails - Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Trying to install rails over ruby:

```
Error :  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>=0) in any repository.
```

Here are my gem env details:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.1
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [i386-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: G:/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:
- C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- G:/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
- :update_sources => true
- :verbose => true
- :backtrace => false
- :bulk_threshold => 1000
- :sources => []
- REMOTE SOURCES:
- SHELL PATH:
- C:\Windows\system32
- C:\Windows
- C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
- C:\PROGRA~1\CONDUS~1\DISKEE~1\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
- C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
- C:\glassfish3\jdk7\bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-1.11\bin
- C:\Users\SKAND.PUROHIT\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin
- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- C:\opscode\chef\bin
- C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, you will need to add `http_proxy` to your environment variable with your proxy address `http://username:password@hostname:port`

If this is not the problem, the easiest and proven way to install rails on Windows is to use the rails installer from http://railsinstaller.org/